# JPivot pivot table by XMLA not working in mondrian

Tags: jsp, mondrian, xmla

I installed the mondrian in my centos.

http://localhost:8080/mondrian/

is shows

Mondrian examples:

```
JPivot pivot table
JPivot pivot table by XMLA
JPivot with 4 hierarchies
JPivot with role 'California Manager' set
JPivot with arrows
JPivot with colors
Various queries formatted using the Mondrian tag-library
Basic interface for ad hoc queries
XML for Analysis tester
```

Other links:

```
Mondrian home page
Mondrian project page
JPivot home page
JPivot project page
```

all link are work fine except

> **JPivot pivot table by XMLA**

Error while click on this link..

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /testpage.jsp at line 44
>
> ```
> 41:
> 42:
> 43: <%-- include query and title, so this jsp may be used with different queries --%>
> 44:
> 45:
> 46:
> 47:
> ```

Stacktrace:

> at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter$MyHandler.normalRequest(RequestFilter.java:139)
>     at
>   com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapException:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid
>   Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP
>   response?     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:904)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:837)
>     at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspService(testpage_jsp.java:290)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     ... 28 more Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapException:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid
>   Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP
>   response?     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:591)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
>     at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspx_meth_wcf_005finclude_005f0(testpage_jsp.java:314)
>     at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspService(testpage_jsp.java:164)
>     ... 31 more Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapException:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid
>   Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP
>   response?     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:904)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:837)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.queries.xmla_jsp._jspService(xmla_jsp.java:130)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     ... 42 more Caused by: com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapException:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid
>   Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP
>   response?     at
>   com.tonbeller.jpivot.xmla.XMLA_SOAP.discover(XMLA_SOAP.java:1453)     at
>   com.tonbeller.jpivot.xmla.XMLA_SOAP.discoverDim(XMLA_SOAP.java:342)
>     at
>   com.tonbeller.jpivot.xmla.XMLA_Model.initCubeMetaData(XMLA_Model.java:737)
>     at
>   com.tonbeller.jpivot.xmla.XMLA_Model.initialize(XMLA_Model.java:173)
>     at
>   com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapModelDecorator.initialize(OlapModelDecorator.java:132)
>     at
>   com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.OlapModelProxy$MyState.initialize(OlapModelProxy.java:77)
>     at
>   com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.StackStateManager.initializeAndShow(StackStateManager.java:76)
>     at
>   com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.OlapModelProxy.initializeAndShow(OlapModelProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.OlapModelTag.doEndTag(OlapModelTag.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.queries.xmla_jsp._jspx_meth_jp_005fxmlaQuery_005f0(xmla_jsp.java:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.queries.xmla_jsp._jspService(xmla_jsp.java:112)
>     ... 45 more Caused by:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid
>   Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP
>   response?     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:149)
>     at com.tonbeller.jpivot.xmla.XMLA_SOAP.discover(XMLA_SOAP.java:1429)
>     ... 55 more Caused by:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid
>   Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP
>   response?     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:655)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:85)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:332)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:145)
>     ... 56 more

Please help me how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Use a full file path to the datasources.xml file in the **web.xml** file e.g. with the mondrian 3.4.1 distribution,

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MondrianXmlaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mondrian.xmla.impl.DynamicDatasourceXmlaServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>DataSourcesConfig</param-name>
      <param-value>file:///c:/tomcat/webapps/mondrian/WEB-INF/datasources.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- 
      This is an example of how to add a callback to the XML/A servlet.
      It must implement mondrian.xmla.XmlaRequestCallback.
    <init-param>
      <param-name>Callbacks</param-name>
      <param-value>com.example.MyCallbackClass;com.example.SomeOtherCallback</param-value>
    </init-param>
    -->
  </servlet>
```